# If PHP file does not exist create it

Tags: php

Let's say you enter a name in an input and then submits the form. I know how to check if that file does not exist, and if doesn't create it. But I want so even if you put it in the URL the file should be created. For example, if you put 'Poxen' in the input and submits, the file will be created. But if you put in the URL like this: https://example.com/users/Poxen I want the file to be created as well.

I have tried to search for this, but I'm a little unsure about what to search for. All I find is how to create a file if it doesn't exist like this: if(file_exists()). But how can I have this code in a file that doesn't exist?

So basically I want to create files through the URL instead of through a form. If you type https://example.com/users/poxen the file poxen should be created in the 'Users' folder.

Comment: Why does each user need their own separate PHP file?

Comment: What you're looking for here is routing.

Comment: Normally you would have one shared PHP file and customize the behavior using a database table lookup or URL/CGI parameters, or similar.

Comment: How are you accessing your PHP script? Is it through a framework, or do you just have a simple script at `example.com/users`?

Comment: I agree with the other commenters. It seems like this _might_ be an XY problem.

Comment: They don't if you know a way to store 25000 characters in a MySQL database.

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate a bit? (By the way, please don't interpret the questions as criticism. Just trying to understand the problem better.)

Comment: Why would you want to store characters in a php file?

Comment: Okay, so I'm using an API to get information for users from a game. This information is the username, user level, user icon, which can be stored in a database. But the problem is when I want to store the user's recent matches played. The match arrays contains a lot of information. Amount of kills, deaths, damage, teammates, it even shows stats for each 10 seconds or something like that. And this information can be up to 25 000 characters long. And MySQL has a limit of 255 charactes, which makes it impossible for me to store all that information in the database.

Comment: Who told you MySQL has a limit of 255 characters? That is simply incorrect.

Comment: The char type is limited to 255, but other text types in MySQL can hold many more characters.

Comment: So is there a way for me to store an array this long in MySQL?

Comment: TEXT. https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/

Comment: Yes, definitely. But I would consider (maybe you already have) whether you need access to the individual data elements in the large text. If so, it may be beneficial to parse it and store the relevant bits in dedicated tables. It will be difficult to get any useful pieces back out if you store it as one big blob of text.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want url rewrites and a script to fetch the information from the game API you mention, this can be done on the webserver, or you could use something with such routing built in out of the box like laravel, symfony, or slim and accomplish the same task

Creating a file per-query at runtime is not the right solution for the question you're asking.

For example, something like the following would work in laravel:

```
Route::get('/players/{username}/', 'PlayerController@show')->name("player.view");
```

Then in your controller,

```
public function show($player)
{
    $statistics = SomeModel::find($player);
    return view('pages.community.view', compact('player', 'statistics'));
}
```

and in your view code you could access your player name and statistics

As for your question about the actual storage of recent matches, that sounds to me like you'd want to just cache the data? you could do that pretty simply with a large binary column and popping json into it or something along those lines.